# Product of a matrix with its cofactor matrix: commutative property

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, inverse

Let A be a square matrix of order $n$. Then we have the following well-known result:

$$\textbf{A}\big(\text{cof}(\textbf{A})\big)^T = \big(\text{det} (\textbf{A})\big) \textbf{I}$$

where $\text{cof}(\textbf{A})$ is the cofactor matrix of $\textbf{A}$. Assume that the determinant of $\text{det} (\textbf{A}) \neq 0$. Then,

$$\frac{1}{\text{det} (\textbf{A})}\textbf{A}\big(\text{cof}(\textbf{A})\big)^T = \textbf{I} \Rightarrow \bigg(\big(\text{cof}(\textbf{A})\big)^T\bigg)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\text{det} (\textbf{A})}\textbf{A}$$

Thus, we have shown that the transpose of the cofactor matrix is not singular, so we can also write:

$$\frac{1}{\text{det} (\textbf{A})}\textbf{A}\big(\text{cof}(\textbf{A})\big)^T = \big(\text{cof}(\textbf{A})\big)^T\frac{1}{\text{det} (\textbf{A})}\textbf{A}$$

or

$$\textbf{A}\big(\text{cof}(\textbf{A})\big)^T =\big(\text{cof}(\textbf{A})\big)^T\textbf{A}$$

How do I prove this commutative property if the determinant is zero: $\text{det}(\textbf{A}) = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that
$$
A\bigl(\text{cof}(A)\bigr)^T=\det(A)I
$$
Our goal is to show
$$
\bigl(\text{cof}(A)\bigr)^TA=\det(A)I
$$
Identically we have 
$$\text{cof}(A)=\Bigl(\text{cof}\bigl(A^T\bigr)\Bigr)^T$$
hence
\begin{align*}
&\bigl(\text{cof}(A)\bigr)^TA=\det(A)I\\[4pt]
\iff&\Bigl(\bigl(\text{cof}(A)\bigr)^TA\Bigr)^T\!=\bigl(\det(A)I\bigr)^T\\[4pt]
\iff&A^T(\text{cof}(A))=\det(A)I\\[4pt]
\iff&A^T\Bigl(\text{cof}\bigl(A^T\bigr)\Bigr)^T\!=\det(A)I\\[4pt]
\iff&\det(A^T)I=\det(A)I\\[4pt]
\iff&\det(A^T)=\det(A)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which is true.

Comment: In the first line of your proof you state $\text{cof}(A)^T\;\text{A} = det(A)I$, but we do not know that. We know only that $A\text{cof}(A)^T = \text{det}(A) I$. There is no justification to do: $A\text{cof}(A)^T = \text{cof}(A)^T\;\text{A}$. This is exactly what I am trying to prove: possibility to exchange the order in this product.

Comment: @John: It's an iff type proof. The argument is a chain of equivalent statements, ending with a true 
statement, hence they're all true.

Comment: Oh, I got it finally, thank you! Nice proof!